# How to get count of object/array in Sightly

Tags: arrays, count, aem, sightly

I am novice to Sightly. How to get the count of an Array elements or an Objects, which is inside a master-object?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do something akin to

${ object['myobject'].length}

you can get more examples and info on arrays in sightly here
http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/sightly-intro-part-3-2/

Answer (score 0):

refer to http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/sightly-intro-part-5-faq/

11. Can I increment a counter in Sightly?

No you can’t. You can use the Javascript-api or Java-api to implement this.