# How to find the size of a sightly list

Tags: java, list, api, aem, sightly

I need to check the size of list in sightly. I have tried resource.size, item.size, itemList.size, resource.listChildren.size, item.listChildren.size, but none of these works.

I'm planning to use Java USE-API, but I have no clue how to start.

```
<sly data-sly-list="resource.listChildren">
    <sly data-sly-list="item.listChildren">
        ${itemList.count} / #I need the total count of item here#
    </sly>
</sly>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate. You have to use write a method to get the size if you can. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178191/how-to-get-count-of-object-array-in-sightly

Answer (score 2):

Since [Resource#listChildren](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling11/org/apache/sling/api/resource/Resource.html#listChildren--) will return an `Iterator<Resource>`, you will not be able to get the size of the list of children from there.

HTL does not offer a way to get the list size either, however it allows getting [interesting properties of the current item](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#226-list):

```
* index: zero-based counter (0..length-1);
* count: one-based counter (1..length);
* first: true for the first element being iterated;
* middle: true if element being iterated is neither the first nor the last;
* last: true for the last element being iterated;
* odd: true if count is odd;
* even: true if count is even.
```

Answer (score 1):

`<sly data-sly-list.demo=“${demo123.items.listChildren}”> <sly data-sly-test=“${demoList.last}”>  ${demoList.count}</sly>`

Test condition-> demoList.last -> demoList.count

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using a variable name for the list.
2. If you have a list inside a list(nested list), it is always recommended to use a variable name.

> ```
> <sly data-sly-list.item="resource.listChildren">
>     <sly data-sly-list.itemList="item.listChildren">
>         ${itemList.length} / #I need the total count of item here#
>     </sly>
> </sly>
> ```

Try using length instead of size and count.
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Java File:

```
private List<MycustomObject> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

HTL:

```
<sly data-sly-use.myCustomModel="my.custom.location.myCustomModel"> 
 ${myCustomModel.myList.size}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can count number of items in sightly/HTL like -

```
<sly data-sly-test.totalItems="${0}"></sly>
<sly data-sly-list.child="${resource.listChildren}">
    <sly data-sly-test.totalItems="${ childList.count }"></sly>
</sly>
```

`${ totalItems }` - this will give you the number of items in the list.

Answer (score -2):

Inside your list, you can use things like ${itemList.count}, but this only works inside data-sly-list:

${item.name} Page ${itemList.index} of ${itemList.count}

Comment: `count` is just an 1-based counter, will not show the total number of items